# How to register user by username and password and confirm password and email by membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to register a user by username and password and confirm password and email in by membership, and i know that about blow method :

> Membership.CreateUser()

it has 4 overloads, but it hasn't a overload which i want, how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

membership doesn't something like this for you! it is better that you compare your password and confirm password by jquery and then if they were equal, and then use this function :

```
Membership.CreateUser(string username, string password,string mail);
```

and about jquery assume that you have two textbox like this :

```
<input id ="password" type="password"/>
<input id ="confirmPassword" type="password"/>
<label class="display" Id="lblerror" >Password not match </label>
```

and the script :

```
         <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#confirmPassword").change(function () {
                        if ($("#password").val() == $("#confirmPassword").val()) {
                            $("#lblerror").addClass("show");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#lblerror").removeClass("show");
                        }
                    });
                });
           </script>
```

and the css is :

```
.show{
 display:none;
```

}

i hope its help you.